# MapStruct: map nested object properties to properties

Tags: java, mapstruct

Assume I have the following objects:

```
class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
}

class PersonBLO {
    Person person;
    Integer foo; // Some calculated business property
}

class PersonDTO {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Integer foo;
}
```

I find myself writing the following mapper:

```
@Mapping(target = "firstName", source = "person.firstName")
@Mapping(target = "lastName", source = "person.lastName")
PersonDTO personBLOToPersonDTO(PersonBLO personBLO);
```

Is it possible to automagically map all `person.*` attributes to the corresponding `*` attributes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now, [with version 1.4](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-nested-bean-properties-to-current-target) and above of `mapstruct` you can do this:

```
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "person")
PersonDTO personBLOToPersonDTO(PersonBLO personBLO);
```

It will try to map all the fields of `person` to the current target.

Answer (score 2):

Using wildcards is currently not possible.

What you can do though is to provide a custom method that would just invoke the correct one. For example:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

default PersonDTO personBLOToPersonDTO(PersonBLO personBLO) {
    if (personBLO == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PersonDTO dto = personToPersonDTO(personBlo.getPerson());
    // the rest of the mapping

    return dto;
}

PersonDTO personToPersonDTO(PersonBLO source);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! So either way I have to implement part of the mapping by hand. Should I create a feature request ticket on GitHub or is this something that does not fit in the roadmap?